# PermissionManager assign roles and permissions UI missing

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I try to use the PermissionManager (I used UserManager previously). The installation seems to work fine. When I manually add entries to "model_has_permission" and "model_has_role" in the database, the changes are reflected in the UI. But when editing the user I have no options to assign roles and/or permissions like it is visible here:

[image]

The installation did not report any errors. What could be wrong or missing?

Comment: have you built your own UserCrudController or you are using the built_in one?

Comment: I use the build-in one.

Comment: Hmm looks to me like you're using Backpack v3 - which hasn't received updates in more than 1 year I think. Any reason you're not moving to Backpack v4? Is this an older project?

Comment: Please check your Chrome Developer Tools if the are any JS errors onpage - that might be it.